# Jenkins Deployment and Monitoring

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

We need to deploy the code on a set of servers, let Jenkins monitor the code for some time (say 2 days) on those servers and if the result is successful, deploy the code on some other set of servers. Is it possible to do? Is there a Jenkins plug-in that exists for this?

We know that this problem can be handled via scripts but we wish to use something already existing. This will help reduce corner cases.

Comment: Please mention/ add information about any other tool also if it can solve the purpose.

Comment: What type of code will you be deploying and how would you be checking if the result is successful?

Comment: The code will be in C++ and there are certain metrics like time to execute certain functions.